# CSS property not showing up for active navigation element using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I know the title is kinda vague, sorry. I could'nt express it easily in one statement. So, anyways.

I'm currently working on my Personal Website. I wanted to have the nav element for the current page to be highlighted a certain color. To do so I wanted to use this:

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item" <?php if($current =='home'){echo 'class = "active"';}?>>Home</a>
```

and the same thing for the other pages. However, "class = "active" is not even being applied to the a tag. My Index pages contains this:

```
$current = "home";
```

and the css for the active class looks like this:

```
.active{
  background-color: #fdfdfd !important;
  color: #3D1c4B;
}
```

I seriously don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I'm missing or is this just something I can't do with an a element?

[Here is what the nav looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qd1t.png)

Comment: The rendered HTML above would be invalid: `<a href="index.php" class="nav-item" class="active">` - you can't have two class properties.

Comment: I think my variable is being unset. I can't figure out why though.

Comment: Voting to close: Check OP's answer below.  Had a JS library that was unsetting it, this question has no future value.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple class tags, you already have one you can't add a second. Try this:

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item<?= $current == 'home' ? ' active' : '' ?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot about that. It still won't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, and would render:  `<a href="index.php" class="nav-item" class="active">` - which has two `class` attributes (not legal).  Modify your PHP like below, to put both classes in the same attribute:

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item<?php if($current =='home'){echo ' active';}?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: @JacobScarani- So, how many people have responded with the exact same response? And all you are saying is "won't work"? Be specific - what does the HTML that is rendered look like? What "won't work"? Is the style not applied? Is the HTML incorrect? What? Be specific, "won't work" is useless.

Answer (score 0):

your code will add 2 classes so that only one class will be applied to your tag.

try like this.

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item <?php if($current =='home'){echo 'active';}?>">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the class in a variable and use it like this:

```
<?php 
$className = '';
if($current =='home'){
$className = 'active';
echo "<a href='index.php' class='nav-item " . $className . "'>Home</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I see your using:

`<a href="index.php" class="nav-item" <?php if ( $current =='home' ) echo 'class = "active"'; ?> >Home</a>`

is wrong, since you will get `class="nav-item" class="active"`, - instead you need to write:

`<a class="nav-item <?php if ( $current =='home') echo 'active'; ?>" href="index.php">Home</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `class` attribute two times in `<a>` tag

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item" <?php if($current =='home'){echo 'class = "active"';}?>>Home</a>
```

it should be like

```
<a href="index.php" class="nav-item <?php if($current =='home'){echo 
 ' active'; }?>" >Home</a>
```